# Can str_replace be safely used on a UTF-8 encoded string if it's only given valid UTF-8 encoded strings as arguments?

Tags: php, utf-8

PHP's `str_replace()` was intended only for ANSI strings and as such can mangle UTF-8 strings. However, given that it's binary-safe would it work properly if it was only given valid UTF-8 strings as arguments?

Edit: I'm not looking for a replacement function, I would just like to know if this hypothesis is correct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. UTF-8 is deliberately designed to allow this and other similar non-Unicode-aware processing.

In UTF-8, any non-ASCII byte sequence representing a valid character always begins with a byte in the range `\xC0-\xFF`. This byte may not appear anywhere else in the sequence, so you can't make a valid UTF-8 sequence that matches part of a character.

This is not the case for older multibyte encodings, where different parts of a byte sequence are indistinguishable. This caused a lot of problems, for example trying to replace an ASCII backslash in a Shift-JIS string (where byte `\x5C` might be the second byte of a character sequence representing something else).

Answer (score 4):

It's correct because UTF-8 multibyte characters are exclusively non-ASCII (128+ byte value) characters beginning with a byte that defines how many bytes follow, so you can't accidentally end up matching a part of one UTF-8 multibyte character with another.

To visualise (abstractly):

- `a` for an ASCII character
- `2x` for a 2-byte character
- `3xx` for a 3-byte character
- `4xxx` for a 4-byte character

If you're matching, say, `a2x3xx` (`a` bytes in ASCII range), since `a` < `x`, and `2x` cannot be a subset of `3xx` or `4xxx`, et cetera, you can be safe that your UTF-8 will match correctly, given the prerequisite that all strings are definitely valid UTF-8.

Edit: See [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652193/can-str-replace-mangle-a-utf-8-encoded-string-if-its-only-given-valid-utf-8-enco/2652345#2652345)'s answer for a less abstract explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this is correct, at least I couldn't find any counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *do* have a counter example: I have a UTF8 encoded settings ".ini' file specifying appliation settings like email sender name. it says something like:

```
email_from = Märta
```

and I read it from there to variable `$sender`. Now that I replace the message body (UTF8 again)

regards
{sender}

```
$message = str_replace("{sender}",$sender_name,$message);
```

The email is absolutely correct in every respect but the sender is totally broken. There are other cases (like explode() ) when something goes wrong with a UTF string. It is healthy before the conversion but not after it. Sorry to say there seems to be no way of correcting this behaviour.

**Edit**: Actually, `explode()` is involved in parsing the .ini file so the problem may well lie in that very function so the `str_replace()` may well be innocent.

Comment: And you’re absolutely positive that your e-mail body is properly declared to be UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Yes, absolutely positive. I have had weird experience when using the explode() before. A simplified example:

function ech1($var){ echo $var; }

function ech2($var){$parts=explode("|",$var); echo $parts[1];}

echo1($var); // no problems

// now get a concatenated result string from db ("Bjorn|Weckström") and use the second function

echo2($concatenated);

An explode()-use version will break the UTF totally every time. And this is for web as well, not for mail only. EDIT: sorry for loss of formatting

Comment: I can second this - `str_replace` completely murders UTF8 strings, and I am not aware of any way of working around it.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot.
From practice I am telling you if you have some multibyte symbols like ◊ etc, and others are non-multibyte it wont work correctly, because there are symbols that take 2-4 to place them, 
`str_replace` takes fixed bytes, and replaces... In result we have something that isn't any symbols trash etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example (string)?