# Get the most used words with special characters

Tags: php, arrays, count, words

I want to get the most used word from an array. The only problem is that the Swedish characters (Å, Ä, and Ö) will only show as �.

```
$string = 'This is just a test post with the Swedish characters Å, Ä, and Ö. Also as lower cased characters: å, ä, and ö.';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count($string, 1, 'àáãâçêéíîóõôúÀÁÃÂÇÊÉÍÎÓÕÔÚ')));
echo '</pre>';
```

That code will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [This] => 1
    [is] => 1
    [just] => 1
    [a] => 1
    [test] => 1
    [post] => 1
    [with] => 1
    [the] => 1
    [Swedish] => 1
    [characters] => 2
    [�] => 1
    [�] => 1
    [and] => 2
    [�] => 1
    [Also] => 1
    [as] => 1
    [lower] => 1
    [cased] => 1
    [�] => 1
    [�] => 1
    [�] => 1
)
```

How can I make it to "see" the Swedish characters and other special characters?

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised by any PHP function with a name starting with `str` not being multi-byte safe. The user comments in the manual suggest alternatives.

Comment: @CBroe `...PHP function with a name starting with str...` where is this function?

Comment: try this function `mb_str_word_count` instead `str_word_count`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17725577/6797531

Comment: @CatalinB Thank you but the output will then be like this: `Array([This is just a test post with the Swedish characters �, �, and Ö. Also as lower cased characters: �, �, and �.] => 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with regex using Unicode punctuation to split the "words" then just a regular array occurrence count.

```
array_count_values(preg_split('/[[:punct:]\s]+/u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [This] => 1
    [is] => 1
    [just] => 1
    [a] => 1
    [test] => 1
    [post] => 1
    [with] => 1
    [the] => 1
    [Swedish] => 1
    [characters] => 2
    [Å] => 1
    [Ä] => 1
    [and] => 2
    [Ö] => 1
    [Also] => 1
    [as] => 1
    [lower] => 1
    [cased] => 1
    [å] => 1
    [ä] => 1
    [ö] => 1
)
```

This was tested in a unicode console, you might want to empose a encoding if you are using a browser. Either make a `<meta>` tag or set encoding within your browser, or send PHP headers.

Answer (score 4):

*All of this is running under the assumption that you're using UTF-8.*

You can take a naive approach using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split your string on any separator, punctuation, or control character.

#### `preg_split` example:

```
$split = preg_split('/[\pZ\pP\pC]/u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r(array_count_values($split));
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [This] => 1
    [is] => 1
    [just] => 1
    [a] => 1
    [test] => 1
    [post] => 1
    [with] => 1
    [the] => 1
    [Swedish] => 1
    [characters] => 2
    [Å] => 1
    [Ä] => 1
    [and] => 2
    [Ö] => 1
    [Also] => 1
    [as] => 1
    [lower] => 1
    [cased] => 1
    [å] => 1
    [ä] => 1
    [ö] => 1
)
```

This works fine for your given string, but does not necessarily split words in a way that is locale-aware. For example contractions such as "isn't" would be broken up into "isn" and "t" by this.

---

Thankfully the [Intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) adds a great deal of functionality for dealing with things like this in PHP 7.

The plan would be to:

- *[Normalize](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) the input with [`Normalizer::normalize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) to make sure graphemes are all encoded in a consistent manner. For example `ä` might be encoded, and hence counted, in a couple ways:

  - U+00E4 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS' or
  - U+0061 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A' followed by U+0308 'COMBINING DIAERESIS'
- Get an [`IntlBreakIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlbreakiterator.php) that breaks on words in a locale-dependent way via [`IntlBreakIterator::createWordInstance()`](http://php.net/manual/en/intlbreakiterator.createwordinstance.php). This understands what makes up a "word" for the given locale, including handling contractions like "isn't".
- Get its [`IntlPartsIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlpartsiterator.php) via [`IntlBreakIterator::getPartsIterator()`](http://php.net/manual/en/intlbreakiterator.getpartsiterator.php) for ease of iterating over the text fragments.
- Skip things you don't care about via [`IntlChar::ispunct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.ispunct.php) and [`IntlChar::isspace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.isspace.php)

*(*Note that you'll likely want to perform normalization regardless of what method you use to break up the string - it'd be appropriate to do before the `preg_split` above or whatever you decide to go with.)*

#### Intl example:

```
$string = Normalizer::normalize($string);

$iter = IntlBreakIterator::createWordInstance("sv_SE");
$iter->setText($string);
$words = $iter->getPartsIterator();

$split = [];
foreach ($words as $word) {
    // skip text fragments consisting only of a space or punctuation character
    if (IntlChar::isspace($word) || IntlChar::ispunct($word)) {
        continue;
    }
    $split[] = $word;
}

print_r(array_count_values($split));
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [This] => 1
    [is] => 1
    [just] => 1
    [a] => 1
    [test] => 1
    [post] => 1
    [with] => 1
    [the] => 1
    [Swedish] => 1
    [characters] => 2
    [Å] => 1
    [Ä] => 1
    [and] => 2
    [Ö] => 1
    [Also] => 1
    [as] => 1
    [lower] => 1
    [cased] => 1
    [å] => 1
    [ä] => 1
    [ö] => 1
)
```

This is more verbose but may be worthwhile if you'd prefer [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) (the library backing the Intl extension) to do the heavy lifting when it comes to understanding what makes up a word.

Comment: Many thanks for a very detailed answer. Both of yours answer and MarZab's answer are very good. Your regex will accept smileys while MarZab's regex will not. If I could, I would accept both answers but since MarZab's regex doesn't accept smileys, I'll accept his answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the � sign by adding `ÅåÄäÖö` into `àáãâçêéíîóõôúÀÁÃÂÇÊÉÍÎÓÕÔÚ`.