# What is Arabic characters Density and how to create a script in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to show the density of words in an Arabic text. The following code works for English characters but does not support the Arabic text. How can I specify the density of Arabic words in the text?

```
<?php
$str = "I am working on a project where I have to find out the keyword density of the page on the basis of URL of that page. But I am not aware actually what \"keyword Density of a page\" actually means? and also please tell me how can we create a PHP script which will fetch the keyword density of a web page.";

// str_word_count($str,1) - returns an array containing all the words found inside the string
$words = str_word_count(strtolower($str),1);
$numWords = count($words);

// array_count_values() returns an array using the values of the input array as keys and their frequency in input as values.
$word_count = (array_count_values($words));
arsort($word_count);

foreach ($word_count as $key=>$val) {
    echo "$key = $val. Density: ".number_format(($val/$numWords)*100)."%<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Example output:

```
of = 5. Density: 8%
a = 4. Density: 7%
density = 3. Density: 5%
page = 3. Density: 5%
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [str\_word\_count() function doesn't display Arabic language properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884178/str-word-count-function-doesnt-display-arabic-language-properly)

Comment: The first step is to understand the problem. You say that you do not yet. This is why you are struggling to get a solution. You will need to know what the word separator is in Arabic (is there one?). The to the task one step at a time, start with getting a list of words.

Comment: Have you considered not using PHP. I hear that the only remaining big users of it is Word Press and Drupal.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Then you are listening to some very strange sources for your information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `str_word_count` doesn't count Arabic characters as "word characters". You can either pass the "word characters" you need as the third argument or just `explode` the string and count the words using a `for` loop.