# PHP Hebrew character count

Tags: php, hebrew

Is there anyway to check count the number of characters for hebrew language.Following is the snippet

```
<?php
 $e_str="This is football";// 3 words
 $h_str="זה כדורגל";//hebrew translation of above
 $h_str= trim(addslashes($h_str)); 
echo 'English Count :  '.str_word_count(mb_convert_encoding($e_str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ISO-8859-1')).'<br/>';//prints 3

echo 'Hebrew Count :  '.str_word_count(html_entity_decode(mb_convert_encoding($h_str,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));//prints zero
?>
```

Probably i should get the Hebrew count as '2' but not zero.
Any solution ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290537/is-php-str-word-count-multibyte-safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just splitting it by a space and counting the array length.

```
echo 'Hebrew Count :  '.count(explode(' ', html_entity_decode(mb_convert_encoding($h_str,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')));//prints 2
```

Comment: ya this works and brings count closer to the actual count..its fine for me thanks @Scimonster