# multi-language str_word_count in php

Tags: php

If I use str_word_count() php function on russian text it will return invalid result. 
The work around is to use something like:

```
function my_word_count($str) {
    return count(preg_split('~[^\p{L}\p{N}\']+~u',$str));
}
```

However , this function may not work with text on another language, complicating the task much more and probably you will have to write individual str_word_count() for every language out there. So, provided that the input may be ASCII or UTF8, does a generic multi-language function exist to count words on any language?

Comment: How does you regex not work with acii? https://eval.in/596594

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19289518/1507679
This question and answer address a similar issue that might help solve your problem. The first answer even lists some of the other unicode characters that are considered spaces.